# How to resize Menu Item(s) in Kendo UI

Tags: css, kendo-asp.net-mvc

All I'm trying to do is change the height of the the menu items! I'm already over it!

[image]

```
        <div id="responsive-panel">


            @(Html.Kendo().Menu()
                 .Name("mainkendomenu")
                  .Items(items =>
                  {
                      items.Add().Text("Alarms").SpriteCssClasses("k-icon k-i-note").Action("Alarms", "Alarms"); 
                      items.Add().Text("Tools").SpriteCssClasses("k-icon k-i-connector");
                      items.Add().Text("Settings").SpriteCssClasses("k-icon k-i-ungroup");
                  })
                .Events(e => e.Open("open").Close("close").Select("select").Activate("activate").Deactivate("deactivate"))


            )

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with.

```
#responsive-panel .k-link
    {
        margin-top:-14px;
        height:5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a simpler way to increase the Menu height is to increase the line-height of the menu items' inner elements:

```
ul.k-menu .k-link{height:100px;}
```

And then modify the icons' positioning by either setting their vertical align property to "middle" (it is "top" by default) or setting some top margin.

Comment: you googled this... I give you no credit for copying and pasting someones findings without reference. Still doesn't work though....